# set the activity in android according to different screens types in android

Tags: android

Hello i have created an activity in XML code in android for 3.7 In WVGA(Nexus One)screen. Now when i tried to see it in different layouts the activity appears different in different screens.I want to adjust it in that manner that it will look same in all screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this page for more information on supporting multiple screen sizes:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html